# Two elements in set builder notation "per iteration"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm looking for a shorthand for $$\{f(x) \mid x \in S\} \cup \{g(x) \mid x \in S\},$$ where it can be assumed that the domains of $f$ and $g$ are disjoint. I would propose:

$$\{f(x),g(x) \mid x\in S\}.$$

However, I have never seen this notation (two elements to the left of $\mid$) in set builder notation before. Is there anything against this proposed notation?

Note that this notation is different from $\{(f(x),g(x)) \mid x\in S\}$, which would be a set of pairs.

---

Perhaps a code example can clarify:

```
new_set = []
for x in S:
    new_set.append(f(x))
    new_set.append(g(x))
```

Or:

```
new_set = [f(x) for x in S] + [g(x) for x in S]
```

(I'm using lists as sets here, I hope you'll forgive me).

Comment: First of all, it seems that what you *actually* want to write is something like
$$
V' = \{v_1,v_2 \mid v_1\in V \text{ and } v_2 \in V\}
$$

Comment: Or, something like
$$
V =\{v_1',v_2' \mid v_1' \in V' \text{ and } v_2' \in V'\}
$$
(it's not clear which of these you mean).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom no, neither of that is what I want. Sorry for the unclarity. For any vertex $v$ I define two other vertices, $v_1'$ and $v_2'$. These other vertices are in $V'$. The intersection of the two sets is $\emptyset$. What I want is a shorthand for $\{v_1' \mid v\in V\} \cup \{v_2' \mid v\in V\}$.

Comment: Second, **why** is it important to you that we don't simply use pairs of the form $(v_1,v_2)$?  Or, perhaps *unordered* pairs of the form $\{v_1,v_2\}$?

Comment: So, you're saying that if $v$ is in $V$, then $v = v_1',v_2'$ for some $v_1',v_2' \in V'$.  That's the second definition I gave.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom please see my edits. For every element in $V$ I want to add two elements to $V'$. Both $V$ and $V'$ are sets of vertices, neither of them contain pairs of each other, and they are disjoint (by the definition of $v_1'$ and $v_2'$). I'm not saying $v=v_1',v_2'$, I'm defining $v_1'$ in terms of $v$ (and similar for $v_2'$).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Don't your first two examples just mean that $V=V'$?

Comment: In what way does an element of $v$ "give you" two elements of $V'$?  One answer is to say that $v$ **is** the pair of elements.  What answer do *you* have in mind?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The "in other words" edit to the question explains that he simply has two functions defined on $V$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom perhaps my example with $v,v_1'$ etc. is unfortunate. In the edit I added an example with proper functions. I would like to introduce $\{f(x), g(x) \mid x\in S\}$ as shorthand for $\{f(x) \mid x\in S\} \cup \{g(x) \mid x\in S\}$.

Comment: @Camil: The closest to a short _standard_ notation for that might be $\bigcup_{x\in S}\{f(x),g(x)\}$, though that will cost the reader a bit of thought to unravel. If you need it many times you could simply use your $\{f(x),g(x)\mid x\in S\}$ notation; just explain what you mean by it beforehand and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. @HenningMakholm is right. I removed the confusing first part (but you can of course check the revision history). // Okay, thank you, HenningMakholm!

Comment: I'd say $f(S)\cup g(S)$ is a shorthand. In terms of standard set builder notation you are free to write $\{y\in Y\mid \exists x\in S\colon y=f(x) \vee y=g(x)\}$, where $f$ and $g$ map $S$ into $Y$.